# Display some special character as a linebreak in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to display some (arbitrary) special character as linebreak <CR> in vim.
So far I tried misusing (certainly extreme misuse:) the non-breakable space typing

`:set list listchars=nbsp:<CR>`

which does not work, seemingly because the command does not accept the <CR>.
Is there anything which I can use here for <CR>? \r didn't work either.

Note that I don't want to edit the text file. The goal is to have blocks of lines (some related code) treated as a single line with respect to vim actions but displayed as multiple lines. The special character (to be defined) would be used only to save this block structure in the file replacing the linebreak \r in these cases.

Comment: Another idea would be to use vim's wrap functionality, configured such that it breaks whathever is longer than one character but only if special character is encountered. breakat option could be used to define this special character. But my first difficulty here is that ":set textwidth=1" does not shorten the lines as I expected.

Comment: It seems that the textwidth option affects only the formating and not (soft-)wrapping which I was insinuating. Is there any similar option for the :wrap command or an option which tells it to always break at a given character?

Comment: Could you please provide a little wider context of the issue?  What problem are you trying to solve by displaying a single physical line as several display lines?

Comment: I have a file of code in some lang. I want to be able to execute it linewise in vim (by assigning a map for filter command). But not all lines in the file can be executed on their own, because they are incomplete. So I need to identify these blocks of code in some way and to send the file blockwise to the filter. The easiest way would be if these individual blocks are treated as single lines internally and only the display is on multiple lines. Each block can consist of code representing whole routines or more. If they belong together can only be determined by the interpreter or by eye.

Comment: I recommend you to paraphrase the question (and its title) basing on your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Given the wider context of the problem that you have provided in a
later comment, I would suggest the following solution. Group dependent
lines of code in folds by indentation, language’s syntax, or markers.
All of these three methods are automatic and do not require manual
creation of folds. Which one to choose depends on the language you
use. See `:help foldmethod`, and feel free to comment this answer if
you need any help with folding.

Unless the syntax of the language you use has extensive support in
Vim, the most convenient methods would be using fold markers or
defining a custom expression to calculate fold level of each line.
The former method implies surrounding every group of lines to fold
with special text markers (which could be enclosed in a comment not
to break the syntax rules of the language). By default, those markers
are `{{{` and `}}}`; see `:help fold-marker` and `:help foldmarker`
to find out how to change them. Use

```
:set foldmethod=marker
```

to enable this mode of folding.

Defining an expression to calculate fold level for every line is an
even more flexible method. It allows to use any logic (that can be
expressed in Vimscript) to determine the fold level. For example, to
fold groups of lines that start with a single space use the following
settings:

```
:set foldmethod=expr
:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)[0]=='\ '
```

See `:help fold-expr` for further details on customizing the fold
expression.

When the lines that depend on each other are grouped into folds, you
can easily pass the contents of any particular fold to a filter
program. Move the cursor to a line inside a target fold, then type
`[zV]z` to select the entire fold, followed by `!`, and enter the
command to run. To save typing, you can define the mapping

```
:nnoremap <leader>z [zV]z!
```

If the command is always the same, you can include it in the mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>z [zV]z!cat -n<cr>
```

Substitute the `cat -n` portion above—my example command—with the
appropriate command in your case.

Comment: @rembremading:  Please, let me know whether this solution works for you or not.

Comment: He hasn't been seen since "Aug 7", and his suggested edit was saying that "comments don't work anymore", meaning that he's no longer using the same account. So, your answer will almost certainly never be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want check out [this vimcasts episode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/). May not be exactly what you want, but could get you there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My solution, in the end, was to insert non-breaking spaces and linebreaks in the respective places in the file. `:set list listchars=nbsp:$` can then be used to display these 'special linebreaks'. Their presence allows interpreting code to identify the blocks of lines separated by this combination as related lines.

Of course this doesn't answer the question. The answer, according to my best knowledge now, is that neither `:set list` nor `:wrap` can be used to achieve this.